# Show python or node print statements in real time while running python script in node web app

Tags: python, node.js, express

I'm developing a node web app right now and it includes a few python scripts. I've got the python scripts running along the nodejs stuff with pyshell but I want to "show" the python script running in my html page the way it would look in Terminal. Currently, the web page displays the information after the python script has finished running. What I want instead is the web page to be updated in real time as the python script runs. So for example, as my python script prints to the console, I want to show it in my web page in real-time - probably with a div styled to look like Terminal and displaying all the print statements from my script. I'm new to NodeJs so I'm not sure if this is possible and/or where to start.

Comment: This post answered my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749383/emitting-messages-from-python-shell-to-a-browser-in-a-node-express-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emitting messages from python-shell to a browser in a Node Express App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749383/emitting-messages-from-python-shell-to-a-browser-in-a-node-express-app)